# Mp4 video not working on iPad *in Offline Mode*

Tags: iphone, html, caching, video, offline

I'm getting a weird problem when embedding an mp4 onto a webpage in iOS Safari. I am embedding it with a video tag:

`<video src='gizmo.mp4' width=560 height=320></video>`

However, on the page, I'm getting the 'video not available' placeholder graphic (play button with a slash through it)

However, when I go to the direct video on my server (http://www.example.com/gizmo.mp4), the video works perfectly.

I am using the video from [here](http://www.808.dk/?code-html-5-video) to test this out, I don't have the final video files yet. I have also replaced the gizmo.mp4 file with a gizmo.m4v file that Quicktime generated when I hit "Export for Web." I get the same result.

I am only interested in targeting iOS, so specific solutions for iPhone/iPad are welcome (even if they wouldn't work in the web at large)

Thanks in advance!
-Esa

**EDIT:** Did a bit more testing. Since this is an offline app that I am working on, I was completely offline for this, relying on the manifest. However, the videos worked once I took the manifest out and was working completely online again. So it looks like something up with iOS not caching video resources? The video in question is 748kB, so it's not a cache size issue (though, when I tries with a 13MB movie online, Safari automatically asked to cache the content)

Answer (score 0):

Videos are regarded by the browser as a streaming resource and are not cached - even when referenced directly in the .appcache manifest file. I think the only way you could get this to work is to package the HTML 5 application up as a native app, using one of the many available tools for this (https://trigger.io, Accelerator etc).